# How to use a summary of a paper that references to another paper?

Tags: publications, citations

Imagine we have a paper A that references to paper B by a summary, if I want to use that summary what is the best course of action?

```
1. Use the A summary and cite to A.  
2. Use the A summary and cite to B.  
3. Write my own summary of B and cite B.
```

As it is my first time to write a paper, I'm not sure which one is the best action and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To comment on the options you present (my comments in bold):

> 1. Use the A summary of B and cite to A. (**Don't do this**)
> 2. Use the A summary of B and cite to B. (**This would generally be poor form; you want to verify the accuracy of the summary and ideally form your own understanding; in extreme cases it could be plagiarism; that said if you are merely using the summary to assist a little in your interpretation, this might be okay.**)
> 3. Write my own summary of B and cite B. (**This is generally preferable**)

When the particular interpretation of A is relevant, another option is to write something like:

> **A**lpha (2015) interprets the work of **B**eta (2013) to mean that ...

In general, the aim is to give credit to intellectual contribution. So if someone does a study or writes a paper, cite the primary source. If you want to summarise what it means cite the primary source.